# Не активна кнопка Full screen video в WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

Делаю приложение kiosk на tablet, использовал WebView для преобразования сайта в приложение, но возникла проблема - Кнопка не активна для full screen видео.
Может кто подсказать, ибо до этого не засовывался в андроид разработку.
Понял, что надо копать в сторону WebChromeClient.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
    tools:targetApi="29">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    getSupportActionBar()?.hide();
    val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    val webSettings: WebSettings = webView.settings
    webView.setLongClickable(true)
    webView.setOnLongClickListener { v ->
        true
    }
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.webViewClient = MyAppWebViewClient()
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
}
```

MyAppWebViewClient.kt

```
class MyAppWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
    view?.loadUrl(url!!)
    return true
}
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```